# How to put bar chart legend values inside the bar itself (so I can remove the legend)?

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi, crystal-reports-2013

*I apologize in advance for the ambiguity here. I don't want to expose any potential intellectual property so I have to generalize.*

I have a bar chart in CR 2013 which shows (top 5) sums of [amount] on the data axis and each bar represents a different [category 1].

The base query is pulling the [amount] from a pre-summarized table, based on a date parameter passed to the query. It is not very complicated. The actual query joins out to tables to pull in names for the ids, but in a nutshell:

```
declare @end_date varchar(15) = '{?endDate}'; -- passed in from main report

select *
from [summary table] s 
where s.[summary date] = @end_date
```

The base data from the query looks like this:

```
[category 1 name & id] | ... | [category n name & id] | [amount] | [..other fields...] | [summary date]
```

with rows for each combination of all [category] fields that has data on the [summary date].

*(This is a very robust, mostly 3nf database; the [category n] columns are all foreign keys to specific objects, e.g. [department_id], [facility_id], [user_id], etc. I don't want to give the impression that this is an EAV schema or something like that.)*

So my bar chart is set up like this:

On change of `command.[category 1 name & id]` show values `Sum of command.[amount]`

I have "show value" checked for the Data Points.

What I would like to accomplish is to move the "Legend" labels (the values of [category 1 name & id]) to the bars themselves, rather than using the legend. I can't seem to find a way to do this easily.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Chart Options -> Axes -> Show Group Axes [checked]